# Recording Kinect V2.0 (Color and depth) using C++ in UWP

Tags: c++, visual-studio, uwp, kinect-v2

I am fairly new to using Kinect V2.0 (or any Kinect for that matter). I am creating a UWP and I am using C++ underneath. I am making everything in visual studio 2017. I am having trouble finding how to record data using the Kinect camera. So far I only found [how to display](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraFrames) the info being read by the camera and [how to save a screenshot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn435684.aspx).

But I didn't found a single video/thread/question talking about how to record the data being read nor how to form a video with it.

Is there any documentation that you could point me to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get more information about the Kinect here:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/kinect.